# Direct user to default page upon accessing Wi-Fi AP 

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, wireless-access-point, captive-portal

Is it possible to set up a default HTML page which anyone connecting to my wireless access point will see, if they try to visit a website after connecting?

I have a Mercury MW54R.

Comment: Which AP do you have? Do you mean some start page like in public WiFis?

Comment: yea exactly just like a start page those public hotspots tend to have... you probably won't know the brand but i have a Mercury MW54R AP.

Comment: Yeah, seems like a model not that common. I just asked because this information is necessary to properly answer your question.

Comment: if i reset the ap then connect first time, it also shows me a page...

Comment: Yes, that is because the firmware of the access point has a small built in web server that allows you to configure the access point. However I haven't heard of one yet that would allow you to set up own sites.

Answer (score 0):

The term for this feature is called "Captive Portal". If you search for that, and possibly look for aftermarket firmware distros that support that feature and run on your router, you can probably figure out if this is something you can do with your current router or if you'll need to get a different router for that.